# How to copy a Google sheet with Python?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

Is there a way to copy a Google Spreadsheet programatically using Python? I am using Gspread to manipulate my Google sheet, but there is no support for this functionality.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python I suggest you use the official API

Comment: I’m kind of new to programming. Can you suggest a code example? Thanks

Comment: please go to the link I provided it has a step by step set of instructions and a basic code example of how to interface with google sheets. It also assumes you are using macOS or Linux shell. If you are on windows I suggest you use cygwin to have a similar shell.

Answer (score 1):

[This library](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets), pygsheets, for the new V4-API solved my problems.

The `add_worksheet`-method did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

There is a google drive API for this , you can find more details in this [link](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html)